# Keep VS Code cursor on screen

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I keep the text cursor (caret) on the screen when scrolling in VS Code with Ctrl + up/down?

I've searched for scroll options, text options, extensions, etc. To no avail.

Comment: the caret is on screen for me using my fresh installed vscode(Linux).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I'm using in `keybindings.json` and it pretty much matches Visual Studio's Ctrl+Up/Down behaviour.  (ie: basically SebastianDB's answer but for both keys and line up/down instead of page.  Also, you don't need the macros extension, it works out of the box).

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+up",
        "command": "editorScroll",
        "args": {
            "to": "up",
            "by": "line",
            "revealCursor": true
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+down",
        "command": "editorScroll",
        "args": {
            "to": "down",
            "by": "line",
            "revealCursor": true
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this myself but have you looked at this yet?

Install this:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros

then add a macro to ctrl+up/down with this sample and change the key from alt+pageup to what you want.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22796

```
{
    "key": "alt+pageup",
    "command": "editorScroll",
    "args": {
        "to": "up",
        "by": "page",
        "revealCursor": true
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Hope it works, have a good one!

Comment: He is just scrolling one line at a time so perhaps you want to modify this.  Otherwise the OP could just use PageUp/Down to get the same behavior as your macro.

Comment: Plus, there is no need for a macro here - just putting your code into the keybindings.json works as is (for PageUp).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something similar like `scrolloff` in vim?
Then add this to you `settings.json`:

```json
    "editor.cursorSurroundingLines": 9999,
```

Comment: In my version of VS-Code (1.51.1) this doesn't stop the cursor going off the screen when `Ctrl-Up` or `Ctrl-Down` are used.

Comment: So it doesn't answer the question posted here that well, but it answered what I googled really well. Thanks!